# Pandas: for each row count occurrence in another df within specific dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following 2 dfs:

df1

```
|company|company_id|   date   |  max_date |
|  A21  |    5     |2021-02-04| 2021-02-11|
|  A21  |    10    |2020-10-04| 2020-10-11|
|  B52  |    8     |2021-03-04| 2021-04-11|
|  B52  |    6     |2020-04-04| 2020-04-11|
-------------------------------------------
```

and
df2:

```
|company|company_id| date_df2 |
|  A21  |    5     |2021-02-05|
|  A21  |    5     |2021-02-08|
|  A21  |    5     |2021-02-12|
|  A21  |    5     |2021-02-11|
|  A21  |    10    |2020-10-07|
|  B52  |    8     |2021-03-07|
|  B52  |    6     |2020-04-08|
|  B52  |    6     |2020-04-12|
|  B52  |    6     |2020-04-05|
-------------------------------
```

Logic:
For each `company` and `company_id` in `df1` i want to count how many occurence are in `df2` where the `date_df2 in df2` is between the `date and max_date from df1`

Expected results:

```
|company|company_id|   date   |  max_date |count|
|  A21  |    5     |2021-02-04| 2021-02-11| 3   | 
|  A21  |    10    |2020-10-04| 2020-10-11| 1   |
|  B52  |    8     |2021-03-04| 2021-04-11| 1   |
|  B52  |    6     |2020-04-04| 2020-03-11| 2   |
 ------------------------------------------------
```

How can this be achieved in pandas?

Code to reproduce the df:

```
 #df1
    list_columns = ['company','company_id','date','max_date']
    list_data = [
        ['A21',5,'2021-02-04','2021-02-11'],
        ['A21',10,'2020-10-04','2020-10-11'],
        ['B52',8,'2021-03-04','2021-04-11'],
        ['B52',6,'2020-04-04','2020-04-11']
        ]
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
    #df2
    list_columns = ['company','company_id','date']
    list_data = [
        ['A21',5,'2021-02-05'],
        ['A21',5,'2021-02-08'],
        ['A21',5,'2021-02-12'],
        ['A21',5,'2021-02-11'],
        ['A21',10,'2020-10-07'],
        ['B52',8,'2021-03-07'],
        ['B52',6,'2020-04-08'],
        ['B52',6,'2020-04-12'],
        ['B52',6,'2020-04-05']
        ]
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list_columns, data=list_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join, then filter matched valeus by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html), aggregate counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and append new column with repalce missing values if necessary:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df1['max_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['max_date'])

df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

df = df1.merge(df2, on=['company','company_id'], suffixes=('','_'))
s = (df[df['date_'].between(df['date'], df['max_date'])]
                   .groupby(['company','company_id'])
                   .size())

df1 = df1.join(s.rename('count'), on=['company','company_id']).fillna({'count':0})
print (df1)
  company  company_id       date   max_date  count
0     A21           5 2021-02-04 2021-02-11      3
1     A21          10 2020-10-04 2020-10-11      1
2     B52           8 2021-03-04 2021-04-11      1
3     B52           6 2020-04-04 2020-04-11      2
```